# Size of array decreased after concatenation

Tags: python, numpy

I have two .npz file and I want to concatenate (also tried with hstack), but after the concatenation is less than the sum of two. I am just wondering, does it reduce the size after concatenation. here is the below code for your reference.

```
from numpy import load
import numpy as np

en_1 = load('encoded_1.npz')
en_2 = load('encoded_2.npz')

en_11 = en_1['arr_0'].reshape(1, -1)
en_22 = en_1['arr_0'].reshape(1, -1)

print("Size of en_1 :"+en_1['arr_0'].shape)
print("Size of en_2 :"+en_2['arr_0'].shape)

#mid = np.hstack((en_11,en_22))
mid = np.concatenate((en_11, en_22),axis=1)

print("Size after concatenation :"+mid.shape)
```

here is the output

```
Output
Size of en_1 : (68226020,)
Size of en_2 : (136340912,)
Size after concatenation : (1, 136452040)
```

Looking for concatenation size to be : (1,204566932)

Looking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
en_22 = en_1['arr_0'].reshape(1, -1)
```

be

```
en_22 = en_2['arr_0'].reshape(1, -1) ?
```

Two time the size of en_11 (68226020) equals (136452040)...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
en_11 = en_11.reshape(1,en_11.shape[0])
en_22 = en_22.reshape(1,en_22.shape[0])
```

And then:

```
mid = np.concatenate((en_11, en_22),axis=1)
```

Comment: I want it on axis =1. If I take on axis = 0, then it take size of first array (2, 68226020)

Comment: What is the target shape you're trying to achieve?